# Incoming number from logcat (ADB) contained dots

Tags: android, adb, logcat

I am using ADB and specifically logcat to capture logs from a real android device. During an incoming call, the caller's number is partially hidden. With what it can be connected? Is there a way to see it in full using ADB?

Comment: For example: 
I/Telecom:SamsungTPhoneCallInfo: updateRelaxMode isSktTPhoneMode : false phoneNumber :+79******797

Comment: maybe it has been partially hidden because of privacy and security reasons...

Comment: Yeah, for sure. I think by default the device hides the number sent to the log. But maybe it can be changed somewhere in the settings? We checked it on another device in another country - the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

That's for sure intentional and cannot be changed. Private data should not be visible in logs!

If your goal is to access specific phone events: don't use logcat. Access it via Tasker app or similar setup (through normal network connection, not USB).

Comment: It's amazing that a similar utility for IOS works flawlessly, giving the incoming numbers in full ...